# Quickly detect local network paths

Tags: python, urllib2

Does Python have a way to quickly detect the existence of a local network path?

I have tried using `os.path.exists` and `urllib2.urlopen`. When the path does not exist, they take at least tens of seconds to detect if the path exists.

Is it possible to reduce the time to less than ten seconds?

This is my test code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
from urllib2 import urlopen

path = "file:////192.168.199.249/Users"
try:
    urlopen(path, timeout=1)
    print "exist"
except Exception, e:
    print "not exist"

if os.path.exists(path):
    print "exist"
else:
    print "not exist"
```

Comment: you url (the "path") seems a windows network shared dir.

Comment: Yes, it is a network Shared directory